# Not able to import mgt elements from Node js application

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I am trying to import from the @microsoft/mgt library in my Node js application and facing issues - can someone help. I am already using Babel for using the ES6 modules.

Am I missing something - I am new to Node :(

export * from '@microsoft/mgt-element';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)
at Module._compile (C:\Users\dip\Python Projects\Classified_2021\Node_2021\Internet_Projects_2021\node-starter-kit-es6-master\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
at Object.newLoader [as .js] (\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
at Object. (\src/index.js:2:1)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 1):

You are importing from microsoft/mgt-element library so change the export to import

```
import * from '@microsoft/mgt-element';
```

besides why you are importing the whole library when you only need some parts of it?
if you only need Providers do this:

```
import {Providers,ProviderState} from '@microsoft/mgt-element';
```